# How to apply the transition on Dynamically created image

Tags: javascript, css

How to apply the transition on the image without hover or click event? I want to apply the transition when image is created dynamically and appear on page transition will automatically apply on it.

HTML

```
<form name="form" id="form">
<label style="font-size:18px"><strong> Name</strong> </label><br><br><div id="error"> </div>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]{0,10}" onBlur="fvalidity()" onKeyUp="capital(this)">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

JS

```
function img(target)
{
    var sample=document.createElement("img");
    sample.src="../cross_script.png";

    document.getElementById("form").appendChild(sample);
    if(target.nextSibling)
    {
        target.parentNode.insertBefore(sample,target.nextSibling);
    }
    else{
        target.parentNode.appendChild(sample);
    }
}
function fvalidity()
{
    var txt="";
    if( document.getElementById("fname").validity.patternMismatch)
    {
        txt="*Only Alphabet max 10 Characters.";
        }
        if(document.getElementById("fname").value=="")
        {
            txt="Field is Empty!!";
         }
        if(txt!="")
        {
            img(document.getElementById("fname"));
            var s=document.getElementById("error");
            s.innerHTML=txt;
            s.style.visibility="visible";
       }
}
```

Comment: what transition? There is none defined in your code.

Comment: Yeah because i dnt know how to apply on it.. i

Comment: So first set up the transition in CSS using :hover as a test.

Answer (score -2):

First Create class in css with your transition code.

**CSS code**

```
.transitionEle
 { 
    //css propertiess 
 }
```

With javascript create element and add class .transitionEle.

Using this way you can use number of times that class and apply on number of elements.

hope you get it. Good Luck ['}

Comment: Can you a liltle bit more explain it.. supose i want to add the rotate(180deg). how it apply transition of rotate that it roate in 2s without hover.

Comment: OP gave plenty of code. Giving just a description in return is not a complete answer. Please show, with code in context, what you mean.